# Clone/Copy unmodifable list

Tags: java, list, copy, clone, unmodifiable

Is there any other option for me to modify an unmodifiable list apart from manual traversal and putting content into new array?

Some developers choose to build APIs this way rather than cloning ..

Comment: Your question is quite self contradicting... If it's an _unmodifiable_ list then it can't be _modified_ by any means... So you're going to have to clone it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many collections accepts another [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) as a constructor argument. You can do something like:

```
List<T> mutable = new ArrayList<>(immutable);
```

And then just deal with `mutable` collection.

Comment: you can also combine `.clear()` and `.addAll(list)` if your list is already initilized